# Выборка статей на PHP5

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Есть php скрипт, который выводит из бд статьи (в теории). Но на практике он выводит только первую запись.

```
  <?php
    @mysql_connect('localhost','admin','123') or die('WRONG CONNECTION('.mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(iskstore);
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_db`");
    $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $htmlformat = '<div class ="article-%s"><div class="a_title"><h2>%s</h2></div><div class="a_text">%s</div></div>';
    echo sprintf($htmlformat, $result['a_id'], $result['a_title'],  $result['a_text']);
    @mysql_close()
  ?>
```

[image: сама таблица]

Я конкретно не врубаюсь в PHP и есть подозрение что нужно было через fetch_assoc() но с ним у меня вообще выводит ошибку. Как сделать чтобы скрипт выгружал все записи?

Comment: чтоб не парится с `array` реально проще `fetch_assoc`..... во-вторых надо в цикле это обрабатывать. и в **[документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-assoc-examples)** есть вполне себе примеры с этим связанные...... и в-третьих: не пользуйтесь расширением `mysql` - оно устарело..... используйте `mysqli` или `pdo` ....... в-четвертых: не используйте заглушки в виде `@` иначе вас изнасилует начальник и старший программист

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вставьте `mysql_fetch_array` в цикл

```
@mysql_connect('localhost','admin','123') or die('WRONG CONNECTION('.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(iskstore);
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles_db`");
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $htmlformat = '<div class ="article-%s"><div class="a_title"><h2>%s</h2></div><div class="a_text">%s</div></div>';
  echo sprintf($htmlformat, $result['a_id'], $result['a_title'],  $result['a_text']);
}
@mysql_close()
```